# Extreme Points with a two dimensional function having a constraint and a bounded region

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given the function $f(x,y)=4x+2y$, I wish to find the extreme points (min,max) given the following constraint: $y=x^{2}+1, -3\leq x\leq 0$

The constraint contains both a condition and a region. Which way should I be using here ? Should it be lagrange multipliers, or should it be an extrema under a bounded region ?

In the second case, how do I find the min/max ? Can I say that the edges points over $y=x^{2}+1$ are (0,1) and (3,10) and there are no local points?

Thank you !

Comment: You should draw a sketch of the part of the graph of $(x,y)$ for the range of interest.  Then lightly rule a few of the contour lines for $f$.  That should make it clear which parts of your problem are solvable by calculus means and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: consider the function $$f(x,y)=f(x,x^2+1)=4x+2(x^2+1)$$ and you got a Problem in only one variable

Comment: Your method give identical results to lagrange multipliers, i.e., one point which is (-1,2) and the value of f there is 0. Am I correct ?

Comment: yes that is correct, there is a global Minimum.

Comment: and $$f_x\ne 0$$ and $$f_y\ne0$$

Comment: I agree, there are no local min/max. My book said that the sum of value of the extrema points is 8. It's a mistake, right ?

Comment: can you post the original Problem please?

Comment: maybe there is a typo

Comment: I did post the original problem

Comment: and for $$-3\le x\le 0$$ we get $$y(-3)=10$$

Comment: yes, but is (-3,10) an extrema point ?

Comment: i think so this Point this situated in the Region of your problem

Comment: Right, the sum is still not 8. If I use your method and create a one variable function, I get 3 points to check (1 local), the sum is 10.

Comment: I got $f(-1,2)=0$, $f(0,1)=2$, and $f(-3,10)=8$.